# error connected with explicit class

Tags: c++

In my Array.h file is declared constructor:

```
  explicit Array(unsigned );
```

and I'm implementing that in Array.cpp:

```
explicit Array::Array(unsigned size ): size(size) {}
```

And I got compile error:

> Only declarations of constructors can be 'explicit'

Where is error?

Comment: Notice that it says declaration, not definition. Then you know where to look and what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need explicit in the cpp file, `Array::Array(unsigned size ): size(size) {}` should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the error message. You should not repeat the `explicit` keyword in the definition.

Answer (score 0):

According to the C++ Standard

> 6 The explicit specifier shall be used only in the declaration of a
>   constructor or conversion function **within its class definition**; see
>   12.3.1 and 12.3.2.

So you may use function specifier `explicit` only when you declare a constructor or conversion function within the class definition.

As for the error message then it is ambiguous because function definitions are also their declarations.:)